# Parse query always returns an empty list

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mongodb-query

I have the following problem:

I have two Android apps: In one app I add data to Mongo DB via Parse and in the other app I want to retrieve the information added from the first app.

**The problem is that in the second app everytime I try to query the DB, I get an empty list. I`ve checked with the API KEY, with the keys from the Mongo DB, and everything seems ok in my app.**

Here is the code for the second app to retrieve information in a RecyclerView

```
public class ParseDb extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId(API_KEY)
            .server("http://injuriesandsuspensions.herokuapp.com/parse/")
            .build()
    );




    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
     defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private List<AboutTeams> aboutTeamsList = new ArrayList<AboutTeams>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private GamesAdapter gamesAdapter;

public void retrieveGamesFromDatabase(){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =    ParseQuery.getQuery("InjuriesAndSuspensions");
    query.whereEqualTo("score", "none");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> gamesList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + gamesList.size() + " scores");
                for(int i = 0; i < gamesList.size(); i++){
                    AboutTeams aboutTeams = new AboutTeams();
                    aboutTeams.setId(String.valueOf(gamesList.get(i).getObjectId()));
                    aboutTeams.setScore(String.valueOf(gamesList.get(i).get("score")));
                    aboutTeams.setHomeTeam(String.valueOf(gamesList.get(i).get("homeTeam")));
                    aboutTeams.setHomeTeamMissing(String.valueOf(gamesList.get(i).get("homeTeamMissingPlayers")));
                    aboutTeams.setAwayTeam(String.valueOf(gamesList.get(i).get("awayTeam")));
                    aboutTeams.setAwayTeamMissing(String.valueOf(gamesList.get(i).get("awayTeamMissingPlayers")));
                    aboutTeams.setDate(String.valueOf(gamesList.get(i).get("gameDate")));
                    Log.d("About Teams " , aboutTeams.toString());
                    aboutTeamsList.add(aboutTeams);
                    gamesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_listview);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    gamesAdapter = new GamesAdapter(aboutTeamsList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(gamesAdapter);

    retrieveGamesFromDatabase();

}
```

Please help as I`ve been struggling with this thing for almost 3 days.

Comment: if you got empty List that is OK if your query doesnt match anything right? You should provide some log or the error you get...

Comment: My query query.whereEqualTo("score", "none"); has this in the database. Not the query is the problem as I don`t get any error. I just get an empty list all the time. I`ve tried also to get all the objects from "InjuriesAndSuspensions", but still comes empty.

Comment: use the dashboard to verify the ACL prop values on the target parse objects and then make sure that the query has either master key or inferred access from the associated users permissions via the ACL on target objects.

Comment: Can you explain more how to do it please? How do I verify the ACL prop values plus the rest ?

Comment: So I`ve tried to create a new object from the app that always retrieves empty list and it seems that it creates, so I have acces to the DB, but I probably don`t have acces to the object I`m trying to retrieve

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea Robert. I have discovered what was wrong and it was related to the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

When I was adding info to the Collection DB,the ParseObject I was using didn`t have this line added where I was initializing Parse in my application:

defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

Complete code on how to initialize Parse:

```
public class AddToDB extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId(API_KEY)
            .server(SERVER_URL)
            .build()
    );


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    **defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);**
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

}